# Dynamic Drag & Drop Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm rather new to javascript. I'm trying to create a platform where I can create infinite amount of boards by drag & drop ing the items in my bottom bar (navbarYuivae). Every new board must also be moveable within the platform. 
In this example of codepen you'll have an already-existing board which you can move around but when you drag a new board from the 'bottom-bar' the newly created board is not moveable. Both of them have the same div structure and class names.
I can not figure why the new board can not be moved around.

Please let me know if you can understand where my mistake is.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Yuivae/pen/xxwqpbq

HTML

```
<div class="navbarYuivae">
   <ul class="workboard-toolbar">
     <a class="baritem" name="board" draggable="true"><i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i></a>
     <a class="baritem" name="text-editor" draggable="true"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
     <a class="baritem" name="volume-control" draggable="true"><i class="fas fa-volume-down"></i></a>
   </ul>
   <ul class="textedit-toolbar"></ul>
 </div>
 <div class="work-board">
   <div class="board-container" name="board">
     <div class="board">
       <a class="board-icon"><i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i></a>
     </div>
     <input class="board-name" type="text" value="New Board" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
//Add New Board

const baritems = document.querySelectorAll(".baritem");
const workBoard = document.querySelector(".work-board");

let draggedItem = null;

for (let i = 0; i < baritems.length; i++) {
  const item = baritems[i];

  item.addEventListener("dragstart", function () {
    if (item.name == "board") {
      // CREATE NEWBOARD
      const newBContainer = document.createElement("div");
      const newBoard = document.createElement("div");
      newBContainer.className = "board-container";
      newBoard.className = "board";
      newBoard.name = "board";
      newBContainer.appendChild(newBoard);
      draggedItem = newBContainer;
    }
    console.log("dragstart");
  });

  item.addEventListener("dragend", function (e) {
    if (draggedItem != null) {
      draggedItem.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
      draggedItem.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
      workBoard.appendChild(draggedItem);
      console.log(workBoard, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
  });
}

// Move in Panel

const boardContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".board-container");

for (i = 0; i < boardContainers.length; i++) {
  boardContainer = boardContainers[i];
  const board = boardContainer.querySelector(".board");

  board.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
  function mousedown(e) {
    console.log(board);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

    let cursorX = e.clientX;
    let cursorY = e.clientY;

    function mousemove(e) {
      let newX = cursorX - e.clientX;
      let newY = cursorY - e.clientY;

      const rect = boardContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

      boardContainer.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
      boardContainer.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

      cursorX = e.clientX;
      cursorY = e.clientY;
    }
    function mouseup() {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the new board cannot be created fromt what you've posted

Comment: I don't think your dragstart listener is properly constructing the html structure for your board.  Any new boards also do not have an event listener on them, so they cannot be dragged.  You have to attach the event listener after you create it.  So you would need something like newBContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);  But you need to move your mousedown event into a different scope.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answers. The event listener is board.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown); which should be on all objects with the class "board-container". So I assumed the new added elements would be selected as they have the same class.
What do you mean I need to move mousedown event into a different scope?